# postgresql insert statment raise an error

Tags: postgresql

```
ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions LINE 3:
        ... stdreason_code ,  remark ,  geom,  kushet_code , collector_
        ... but the number of columns and their value are equal.

insert into "ISIMS".wlke_mesno(owner, gender, code, wdabe_code,  leadmember, site_name,
    source_type_code, scheme_type_code, year, constructed_by, funded_by, dev_round,
    pump_type_code, func_code, reason_code, x, y, z, potential_area, stdreason_code,
    remark, geom, kushet_code, collector_code)
  select "owner character varying,", "gender character varying", "code numeric",
         "wdabe_code integer", "leadmember numeric", "site_name character varying",
         "source_type_code integer", "scheme_type_code integer" "year numeric",
         "constructed_by character varying/funded_by", "constructed_by character varying/funded_by_1",
         "dev_round numeric", "pump_type_code integer", "func_code integer",
         "reason_code integer", "x numeric", "y numeric", "z numeric",
         "potential_area double", "stdreason_code integer", "remark character varying",
         geom, "kushet_code integer", "collector_code integer"
  from holder."dump (6)";
```

Comment: simple counting - 24 column with 23 columns in select... you miss year ,

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `,` here: `"scheme_type_code integer" "year numeric"`.